# issue when accessing datetime value from async task

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to insert an event on my Google calendar. Everything is working fine but only problem is that when I change the value of my datetimepicker, it doesn't change at the time of execution. for example, if I change the value of datetimepicker to "2014-07-25", it still will show on MessageBox as current date.

Here is my code :

```
private void btnsubmitevent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        new frm_addeventcal().Run().Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        foreach (var exi in ex.InnerExceptions)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + exi.Message);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}

private async Task Run()
{            
    UserCredential credential;
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "my cliend id",
            ClientSecret = "my secret key"
        },
        new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar},
        "my gmail id",
        CancellationToken.None
    );

    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "project name",
    });

    Event newevent = new Event();
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime();
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime();

    start.DateTimeRaw = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    MessageBox.Show(start.DateTimeRaw); // here it shows current date although I changed the value of it.

    end.DateTimeRaw = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "T" + dateTimePicker4.Value.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    MessageBox.Show(end.DateTimeRaw); // same thing happens here too.

    newevent.Summary = "Hello World";
    newevent.Location = "my location";
    newevent.Description = "Random Description";
    newevent.Start = start;
    newevent.End = end;
    var calendarstry = service.Events.Insert(newevent, "calendar id").ExecuteAsync();
}
```

G

I am new to google api and async task. but I think this problem is because I am using async task.

Comment: First off, don't do `new frm_addeventcal().Run().Wait();`. Make your event handler `async` and `await` the `Run` method.

Comment: In your example you do `new frm_addeventcal().Run()...` Wouldn't that call the run method as soon as the form is created so that you never have the chance to change the DateTimePickers' values before they are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is that you're calling the `Run` method on `frm_addeventcal` immediately when you create the form:

```
new frm_addeventcal().Run()...
```

That doesn't give you a chance to change the values of the DateTimePickers' before their values are used which is confusing because you say you do change the values.

You should create `frm_addeventcal` like this:

```
var form = new frm_addeventcal();
form.ShowDialog();
```

And then you'd want to wait until the datetime's are set before calling `Run`. I think you'd want to display the form while letting the user change the date values and only when the user clicks submit will you execute `Run`:

```
public class frm_addeventcal : Form
{
    public frm_addeventcal() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        await Run();
    }

    private async Task Run() {
        // the DateTimePickers' values should be correct here since this wont 
        // run until submit is clicked
    }
}
```